# Convert a TCP Socket to a TLS one for StartTLS

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, tls1.2

I am trying to write a client to connect to an Openfire server.
Before my Client I am using an other Openfire Server and when the connection between both is launched I can see this on WireShark:

Different TCP exhanges on the server port then the TLS Handshake on the same port.
The TCP requests are saying this:

```
Client :
<stream:stream xmlns:db="jabber:server:dialback" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:server" from="X" to="Y" version="1.0">

Serveur :
<stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:server" from="X" id="e4f15a89" version="1.0">
<stream:features><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.tridsys.com/TacticalChatServer" ver="y397tZ3lcMRCMkGER0wpix00iPk="/>
    <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls>
    <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"></mechanisms>
    <sm xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"><optional/></sm>
</stream:features>

Client :
<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>

Serveur :
<proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
```

Then, I imagine that before the TLS communication the two servers are saying each other if they can communicate with TLS and if the answer is yes they start the TLS Handshake. This is what they call the StartTLS.

So I want to replicate this situation with Java. This is what I am trying:

```
public class ClientTrustAll {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Create trust manager which accept all certificates
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // Accept all certificate for client
                    System.out.println("Check client => OK");
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // Accept all certificate for server
                    System.out.println("Check server => OK");
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            
            // Create trust manager
            TrustManager[] tms = new TrustManager[1];
            tms[0] = tm;
        
            // Create TCP socket
            
            Socket sTcp = new Socket("162.0.126.2", 5269);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sTcp.getOutputStream());
            dos.write(5);
            
            // Create TLS context
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            context.init(null, tms, new SecureRandom());
            
            // Create TLS socket with the Tcp one
            SSLSocketFactory sslf = context.getSocketFactory();
            System.out.println("Talk to 162.0.126.2");
            SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sslf.createSocket(sTcp, "162.0.126.2", 5269, true);

            // Start TLS handshake (may be omitted, then it will be done during first read or write) 
            //s.startHandshake();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            
            // Write "int"
            s.getOutputStream().write(5);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I am doing that, I am getting the following Error message:

```
Talk to 162.0.126.2
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at ClientTrustAll.main(ClientTrustAll.java:63)
```

which means that my server port isnt a TLS port (because it is still TCP).
And on Wireshark I have an Alert Fatal Error just after the Client Hello for the same reason.

I precise that I am using java jdk.1.8.0_121

Comment: This means your server isn't properly sending a TLS handshake. So where is your server code?

Comment: I dont have a server code. It is an Openfire Server which is a very old version (I cant upgrade it)

Comment: If you're trying to do this with actual Openfire server then you must comply with the protocol that server is implementing. Just sending the byte 5 down the wire doesn't cut it. Remember, there is nothing magical about the port, there is no such thing as a "TLS port". If you want to do starttls with this server you'll have to at least send `<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>` to the server and read its response before `sslf.createSocket()` call. You might also have to send everything else, I'm not familiar with the protocol in question here.

Comment: I sent all the message now the server is answering me but I still can't reach it with TLS. Working on it. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer for those who maybe need it.
I had to wait for the server to answer me and then send him the good combination of message to recreate a standard exchange and force him to switch to tls mode.

```
public class ClientTrustAll {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
            // Create trust manager which accept all certificates
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // Accept all certificate for client
                    System.out.println("Check client => OK");
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // Accept all certificate for server
                    System.out.println("Check server => OK");
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            
            // Create trust manager
            TrustManager[] tms = new TrustManager[1];
            tms[0] = tm;
        
            // Create TCP socket
            Socket sTcp = new Socket("162.0.126.2", 5269);
            
            //For reading
            // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sTcp.getInputStream()));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sTcp.getInputStream());
            byte[] messageByte = new byte[1000];
            String dataString = "";
            
            //Writing the first message on this socket
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sTcp.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println("<stream:stream xmlns:db=\"jabber:server:dialback\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" xmlns=\"jabber:server\" from=\"X\" to=\"Y\" version=\"1.0\">");
            System.out.println("Sent: <stream:stream xmlns:db=\"jabber:server:dialback\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" xmlns=\"jabber:server\" from=\"X\" to=\"Y\" version=\"1.0\">\n");
            
            // Read the answer to send response at the good time
            while (!dataString.contains("stream:features")) {
                int bytesRead = in.read(messageByte);
                dataString += new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.println("Answer = " + dataString + "\n");
            }
            
            // Writing the second message on the socket
            out.println("<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>");
            System.out.println("Sent: <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>\n");
            
            while (!dataString.contains("<proceed")) {
                int bytesRead = in.read(messageByte);
                dataString += new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.println("Answer = " + dataString + "\n");
            }
            
            // Create TLS context
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            context.init(null, tms, new SecureRandom());
            
            // Create TLS socket
            SSLSocketFactory sslf = context.getSocketFactory();
            System.out.println("Talk to 162.0.126.2");
            SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sslf.createSocket(sTcp, "162.0.126.2", 5269, true);

            // Start TLS handshake (may be omitted, then it will be done during first read or write) 
            // s.startHandshake();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            
            // Write "int"
            s.getOutputStream().write(5);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```